# Postgresql: How to give the database owner permissions to public-schema?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have a role who needs the ability to create new databases (for several test scenarios). This role should have its permissions only in self-created databases, that's why I do not want to set the necessary permissions in the template-db.
And now I wonder why the owner of a database does not have any rights on *public*-schema too. I thought, an owner has all rights inside his own database. And he does in self-created schemata of course, but not in the *public*-schema. How can I give automatically this role *USAGE* and *CREATE* also in the *public*-schema without giving *GRANT*-rights to it?
I can't delete and recreate the *public*-schema, I can't execute `ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO CURRENT_USER` without extra permissions having effects also on other databases. I need a solution that is working automatically inside an application, preferably without help of a superuser with *GRANT*. Is that possible?

**EDIT:** Version is 13.2. I have revoked the default privileges for *public*, because I have multiple databases on the instance and I wanted the accounts strictly splitted, an account shouldn't have permissions on other databases than the one for it's created. Sure, I can keep the default permissions for *public* and only restrict access to other databases (*CONNECT*), but I didn't so, it seemed a little bit inconsequent to me.

After some additional research and your valueable comments here I think, it's not possible. So I see two alternative approaches:

1. like I said, I do not revoke the default permissions for *public*, but restrict or allow access only with *CONNECT* to a database
2. I remove the *public*-schema from the template and recreate it, if there is a need for it; then the owner of the database would have all rights on it, I assume

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Please show the sequence of commands to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

Up to PostgreSQL v14, everybody has `USAGE` and `CREATE` on the `public` schema by default. This may change in v15.

However, the schema is owned by the bootstrap superuser (usually called `postgres`), so nobody else is allowed to grant or revoke privileges on it.